# How to search in returned json result

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2

I am trying to find away to search in returned json result. the returned result like :

```
{"Result":["Css","java","jquery","asp.net","mvc","javascript","asp","c#"]}
```

I want to get all the words that starts with "j" in an  array or another json object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunatly, there is no `searchJSONandReturnAllEntrysStartingWith('J')` method. But you can do it easily yourself.

```
function searchJSONandReturnAllEntrysStartingWith(ch){
        var jsonres = window.JSON.parse('{"Result":["Css","java","jquery","asp.net","mvc","javascript","asp","c#"]}'),
        filter  = [];

    filter = $.map(jsonres.Result, function(elem, i){
        if(elem.charAt(0) === ch) return elem;
    });

    return filter;
}

alert(searchJSONandReturnAllEntrysStartingWith('j'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var jsonres = window.JSON.parse('{"Result":["Css","java","jquery","asp.net","mvc","javascript","asp","c#"]}'),
        filter  = [];

    filter = $.map(jsonres.Result, function(elem, i){
                        var wordLength = $("#textbox1").val().length;
                        var beforeEnd = wordLength - 1;
                        var ch = $("#textbox1").val().substring(beforeEnd,wordLength);
        if(elem.charAt(beforeEnd) === ch) return elem;
    });

    return filter;
```

I have modify it like that if you have a better solution kindly tell me.